# Vue 3 - Vue.config.js: Proxy problem: Replace the host from the income url

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I installed and configured the vue project "conduit" from [this page](https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app). My goal is to rewrite specific image request to a specific host.

It ends up with the error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /very_special_image_123456.jpg from localhost:8080 to https://destinationurl.com/ (ENOTFOUND).
```

Within the vue app I created the webpack config file called "vue.config.js" and filled with content:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "^/very_special_image": {
                target: "https://destinationurl.com/",
                changeOrigin: true,
                ws: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Example:
http://localhost:8080/very_special_image_123456.jpg

Should be rewritten to:
https://destinationurl.com/very_special_image_123456.jpg

Comment: It can be done anything, goal is to keep the url path after the host and just change the host itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself...

The problem was that my target network was unknown on my mashine so that the `Proxy error` appeard...